# Android listview filter can't get to certain activity

Tags: android, listview

Hello I have an activty which has a listview, autocomplete textview which also if user fills in his entry, it filters the listview. Now when I would click the item from my string array, it's not getting to the intended activity. Please check my code below:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView tv;
ArrayList<String> classesList = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( classes ) );

int textlength = 0;

ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

lv = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.lvFruits );
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setAdapter( new MyCustomAdapter( classes, imagesID ) );
    lv.setOnItemClickListener( this );

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.my_list_item, classesList );  

    tv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById (R.id.txtSearchFruit);
    tv.setThreshold( 1 );
    tv.setAdapter( adapter );
    tv.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );


/**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
                textlength = tv.getText().length();
                text_sort.clear();
                image_sort.clear();

                for(int i=0; i < classes.length; i++)
                {
                 if (textlength <= classes[i].length())
                 {
                  if (tv.getText().toString().
               equalsIgnoreCase((String) classes[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                  {
                   text_sort.add( classes[i] );
                   image_sort.add( imagesID[i] );
                  }
                 }
                }

                lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
                         (text_sort, image_sort));
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selected = classes[lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()+position];

    if( selected.equals("Apple") ){
        Intent apple = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apples.class);
        startActivity(apple);
    }
    else if( selected.equals("Apricot") ){
        Intent apricot = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apricots.class);
        startActivity(apricot);
    }
    else if( selected.equals("Avocado") ){
        Intent avocado = new Intent(Fruits.this, Avocado.class);
        startActivity(avocado);
    }
}

final String[] classes = new String[] { 
        "Apple", // #0
        "Apricot", // #1
        "Avocado" // #2 }
```

What's happening is that, when I chose Avocado, it goes to Apples Activivty. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if user fills in his entry, it filters the listview. Now when I would click the item from my string array, it's not getting to the intended activity.

When you filter your ListView you change the index, so you cannot rely on `position` to fetch the correct row from `classes`. Simply fetch the word in the row:

```
String selected = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
```

---

It looks like you created a unique Activity for item in `classes`... That is a lot of work, you should try to create one *generic* class that can load the appropriate data depending on the user's selection. This approach is much faster to write and easier to maintain.

Comment: Hello can you give me some inputs to do that? thanks. Im new to android. and I tried ur above code but logcat says ClassCastException. android.widget.Relativelayout

Comment: I didn't notice you were using a custom Adapter try `String selected = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.xxx)).getText().toString();` (where `xxx` is the appropriate id.) As for designing a generic Activity, start with [passing data between Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/1267661) and build upon this notion of dynamically reading data.

Comment: wow! I tried your code and it's working fine! God bless you !

Answer (score 0):

to solved this error use this

```
tv.setThreshold( 2 );
```

instead of this

```
tv.setThreshold( 1 );
```

**EDIT :**

For item selection use this easiest way.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(classes[position].compareTo("Apple")==0){
        Intent apple = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apples.class);
        startActivity(apple);
    }
     if(classes[position].compareTo("Apricot")==0){
        Intent apricot = new Intent(Fruits.this, Apricots.class);
        startActivity(apricot);
    }
     if(classes[position].compareTo("Avocado")==0){
        Intent avocado = new Intent(Fruits.this, Avocado.class);
        startActivity(avocado);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello if(classes[position].compareTo("Apple")){ has errors cannot convert from int to boolean

Comment: @ bEtTy Barnes i am sorry that i missed. checked my editable answer.

Comment: This doesn't account for filtering. If `Apple` has been filtered out and the user selects the first item in the filtered list (`position` is 0), then `classes[position]` will always return `"Apple"`...